# Full REST operations for a partial view in a div - MVC 4 & JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application which I am developing which uses a Partial view to render a wishlist. I would like this PartialView to be rendered inside a div within the main page.
The wishlist contents are held within the HttpContext.Profile object for persistence.

Within the partial view controller there are add & remove functions which ideally once performed, would trigger a refresh of the Index action.

I am able to render the partial view within the div, on any action being performed however the whole page gets redirected to the results page rather than reloading the div, I am unaware of how to attain this

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var wish = WishListForm;

    //Perform lookup of any object id's located in the profile.
        if (wish.Properties.Any())
        {
            viewModel.Items = Nav.GetItems(wish.ItemIds).ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("RequestFormPartial", viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult AddItem(int itemId)
    {
        var wish = WishListForm;
        if (!wish.Properties.Contains(itemId))
        {
            wish.Properties.Add(itemId);
        }
        WishListForm = wish;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult RemoveItem(int itemId)
    {
        var wish = WishListForm;
        if (wish.Properties.Contains(itemId))
        {
            wish.Properties.Remove(itemId);
        }
        WishListForm = wish;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult RemoveAllItems()
    {
        var wish = WishListForm;
        wish.Properties.RemoveAll(x => true);
        WishListForm = wish;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Html
    
    WISHLIST

```
<script>
    $('#wishListTest').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "MyData")',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#wishlist").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I assume it's the RedirectToAction which has to change? Any ideas?

Comment: You have to return the same PartialView updated, and then populate the whishlist after the ajax call ends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to just reload the partial view. Not the whole page. What you can do is, If your Add request is coming from an ajax call, return the content for the partial view.

So let's make a small update to the action method to check whether the call is an ajax call or not.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem(int itemId)
{
    var wish = WishListForm();
    if (!wish.Properties.Contains(itemId))
    {
        wish.Properties.Add(itemId);
    }
    WishListForm = wish;
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        //return the viewmodel with Items loaded
        var vm=new YourWishListViewModel();

        if (wish.Properties.Any())
        {
           vm.Items = Nav.GetItems(wish.ItemIds).ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("RequestFormPartial", vm);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Also make sure to prevent the default behavior of button click(it may submit the form). You may use the `preventDefault` method to do that.

```
$('#wishListTest').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // your ajax posting code goes here
});
```